# Is it necessary to create a DNS record for "website.com" when create one for "www.website.com"

Tags: dns, webserver

When I create a DNS record for website "www.website.com", is it necessary to create a record for "website.com" first?

Answer (score 1):

You have to have NS and SOA records for website.com. You don't technically have to have an A record, but I would recommend that you do.

Comment: Pardon me for my lack of knowledge. Do I need to specify an IP address for an SOA record?